# Merge keys with the same value in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists and would like to obtain just one key in case of keys with duplicated values. For example:

```
dic1 = {8: [0, 4], 1: [0, 4], 7:[3], 4:[1, 5], 11:[3]}
```

resulting dictionary

```
dic2 = {1: [0, 4], 7:[3], 4:[1, 5]}
```

The strategy would be to reverse the values in keys, which would become unique, and then again reverse the keys to their respective values:

```
dic2 = {y: x for x, y in dic.items()}
```

But an error occurred because lists are not hashables. What I could do to obtain a dictionary with only one key in case of keys with the same value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the lists into tuples, which are hashable.

```
dic2 = {tuple(y): x for x, y in dic.items()}
```

You can convert back into a list afterward if you like:

```
result = {v:list(k) for k,v in dic2.items()}
```

Comment: Works fine TigerhawkT3. Thanks!

Comment: What I can do to store de highest key in this case?

Comment: @RafaelFrinhani - `max(result)`

Comment: For example, dic2 = {8: [0, 4], 4:[1, 5], 11:[3]}

Comment: @RafaelFrinhani - Oh, I see. Sort the dictionary first: `dic2 = {...in sorted(dic.items())}`.

Comment: Thanks @Tigerhawk.